# Error running emulator on android

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm trying to run a phonegap app on android and when i run the command

`phonegap run android --emulator  --verbose`

I am getting this error

`Running command "getprop emu.uuid" on emulator-5554...`

How do i fix this, any ideas? I tried opening it via both command line and android studio emulator hands in both.

Comment: Deleting the AVD and recreating it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

I have found that if I manually start the AVD before issuing the run command then I do not get this error. Also I  found that running an older version of android solves this issue. I do not know exactly how this happens. Running windows 10.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I'm on Windows 7 and I'm finally able to see my app in the emulator when I first start manually start the AVD.

Comment: Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error on a Android 6.0 API Level 23 Device with cordova on fedora 23 with qemu.

It would run the `cordova emulate android` and the emulator would show but the app wouldn't install or open in the emulator.

My problem was caused by cordova trying to wait for the device to be ready by polling `getprop emu.uuid` on the adb shell.

Running `getprop emu.uuid` in the adb shell didn't yield any results. Looking at the output of `getprop` shows that an available property is `dev.bootcomplete`.

I fixed it by changing the following code in platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js (around lines 215-230) to wait for `dev.bootcomplete` to be 1 instead of polling `emu.uuid`:

```
module.exports.wait_for_emulator = function(uuid) {
        ...
        new_started.forEach(function (emulator) {
            promises.push(
                //Adb.shell(emulator, 'getprop emu.uuid') REMOVE THIS
                Adb.shell(emulator, 'getprop dev.bootcomplete')
                .then(function (output) {
                    //if (output.indexOf(uuid) >= 0) { REMOVE THIS
                    if (output == 1) {
                        emulator_id = emulator;
                    }   
                })  
            );  
        });
   ...
```

This may break when you're running multiple emulators at once.

It looks like the problem is with the emulator. cordova runs `emulator -avd <device-name> -prop emu.uuid=cordova_emulator_<date>` but `emu.uuid` isn't properly set in the emulator.

Hope this helps somebody.