# Cannot launch AVD in emulator: 'std::logic_error'

Tags: android, c++, intellij-idea

I'm running Intellij Idea, and I'm trying to run my app. But I keep getting the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The closest I've gotten to an answer [was this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521159/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-android-studio)
But his solution isn't applicable to me since my android location is correct:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Here's the entire message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.868 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
C:/Users/User/IdeaProjects/testapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_101
No emulator specified, defaulting to AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova
Waiting for emulator to start...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: BTW, as far as the app itself. It's just automatically generated code I made using Ionic Creator.

Comment: hi, try to create another emulator and run it as standalone

Comment: Okay, I did. It runs fine, I think. All I get is a black screen.

Comment: @piotrek1543 sorry, forgot to tag you in comment above.

Comment: @piotrek1543 Changing emulators got rid of the error, but the screen is just black. So the problem must've been in the first emulator. Thanks allot for the help. [This post I think covers the black screen issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390391/error-running-emulator-on-android/36588726)